# BubbleChart is not using the label function

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I have created a BubbleChart and I've set the label function as shown below. However, it's not getting called.

```
    <mx:BubbleChart width="100%" height="100%"
                    minRadius="3" maxRadius="16"
                    color="#ffffff"
                    dataProvider="{dataSet}">

        <mx:series>
            <mx:BubbleSeries >
                <mx:verticalAxis>
                    <mx:LinearAxis labelFunction="axisLabelFunction"/>
                </mx:verticalAxis>
            </mx:BubbleSeries>
        </mx:series>

    </mx:BubbleChart>
```

And the function call:

```
        public function axisLabelFunction(labelValue:Object, previousValue:Object, axis:IAxis):String {

            if (labelValue) { // breakpoint here - never triggered
                trace("value");
            }
            return "";
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I was defining the label function in the verticalAxis of the BubbleSeries and it should be in the verticalAxis of the BubbleChart:

```
    <mx:BubbleChart width="100%" height="100%"
                    minRadius="3" maxRadius="16"
                    color="#ffffff"
                    dataProvider="{dataSet}"
                    >

        <mx:series>
            <mx:BubbleSeries />
        </mx:series>

        <mx:verticalAxis>
            <mx:LinearAxis labelFunction="axisLabelFunction" />
        </mx:verticalAxis>

    </mx:BubbleChart>
```